# ¿Como opero 2 valores, ambos de distintas clases en una clase aparte en java?

Tags: java

buenas tardes deseo saber ¿Como operar 2 valores, ambos de distintas clases en una clase aparte en java? ya que busco operar (comparar, sumar, restar, dividir, etc) dos valores enteros ingresados por teclado; dichos atributos los tengo convertidos en objetos pero no tengo clara la lógica a aplicar para poder operar entre objetos, muchas gracias de antemano por responder

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar un __[mcve]__ para que quede mas clara tu pregunta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que no necesitas 2 objetos para eso , pero respondiendo a lo que vos queres , Supongamos tenes el Objeto A y el Objeto B

```
public class Objeto A {

int numero A ; 

}

public class Objeto B {
int numero B 
}
```

suponiendo que tenes los get y seters , para luego operar solo necesitas hacer

> int resultado = B.getNumeroB + A.getNumeroA ;

y asi la operacion que quieras

Comment: hola bruno, muchas gracias por tu respuesta, para serte más claro, el objetivo real que tengo es interactuar entre datos de distintos vectores de diferentes clases, cuando menciono interactuar hablo de operar y reemplazar datos, vos me entendés. Ahora, con el ejemplo que me muestras, esa misma lógica se puede aplicar en el tema de vectores?nuevamente muchas gracias

Comment: Si Miguel puedes hacer todo lo que imagines entre objetos , lo importante es que para utilizar los datos de un  objeto , debes pedirselos ,en este caso atravez de los GETS y SETS . pero podria tener un metodo que devuelva cosas , por ejemplo  si OBJETOA , tiene que mandarte el numero al cuadrado , podrias hacer un metodo que sea , public int numeroAlCuadrado(){ return this.numeroA*numeroA; } y de la otra clase solo llamas a ObjetoA.numeroAlCuadrado ,